# EXC_BAD_ACCESS from task_for_pid()

Tags: c++, c, macos

I'm trying to use `task_for_pid()` for the ultimate goal of reading another (non-system) process' memory through `vm_read()`.  However, whenever I run my code as root, I get an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error flag whenever `task_for_pid()` is executed.  Is there a newer alternative for OSX that I'm overlooking?

Comment: Are you sure `task_for_pid()` is the reason for EXC_BAD_ACCESS? Probably the return value is negative (If it returns a permission error, there are other resources for this problem!) and therefore leads to an invalid access in the following code? Also, while this _should_ not be the reason, did you try disabling SIP?

Answer (score 1):

Before El Capitan (10.11), in order to call `task_for_pid`, the calling process must either be root, or a member of the procmod group, else the function will fail.

Since El Capitan's introduction of System Integrity Protection (SIP - aka rootless), calling task_for_pid is no longer possible for processes that are marked as part of SIP, which mostly are processes that are part of the operating system or provided by Apple.

In order to call task_for_pid under El Capitan, the calling process must be signed witha special entitlement in its certificate, which is currently only available to Apple and not to developers.

You can [turn off SIP](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-os-x-10-11) by booting into Recovery Mode, but this is not recommended for production code, as it disables multiple security systems, such as protection from running unsigned kernel extensions and modifying system files.

Comment: Would this be an issue if I'm trying to read the memory of a third party process?

Comment: No, it won't as the 3rd party process can't have a certificate with the rootless entitlement. If this is still causing an issue, ensure that the process calling task_for_pid is running as root.

Comment: Hmm. The process that I'm using is running as root (without root I get a seg fault). Which is a bit curious, because the seg fault seems to originating from the `task_for_pid()` line, even though (from my understanding) the function doesn't actually access memory (which would be `vm_read()`).

Comment: Are you handling the return from calling task_for_pid, or still calling vm_read even if it fails? Perhaps updating your question with a code example would be beneficial.